# How can I get the specific element value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

<--one or more this-->

```
<Supplement>
<ID>321
    <SupplementType>
        <Glass>31DK</Glass>
    </SupplementType>
</ID>
</Supplement>
```

When I use a value-of select of the current element it gives me 32131DK (value of both the "ID" and the "Glass" element)

In my output I would like to get the number value after the "ID" element only (321)

The xml input cannot be changed, as it is as-is from the manufacturer.

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:element name="ProfileSpecification">
    <xsl:for-each select="Supplement/ID">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each> </element>
```

Output I get:

```
<ProfileSpecification>32131DK</ProfileSpecification>
```

Output I want:

```
<ProfileSpecification>321</ProfileSpecification>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach does not work because

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

returns the *string value* of the context element. The string value is the concatenation of all descendant text nodes, not only the immediate children.

You should not simply match `/` (I guess you do) and fit all the code inside this single template. Rather, define separate template matches for the elements that are important and use `apply-templates` to move through the document.

Do not use `for-each` without good reason. The same goes for `xsl:element` - do not use it if the element name is statically known, use a *literal result element* instead.

**XML Input**

Assuming a well-formed (a single root element) and representative (multiple `Supplement` elements, as you state in the question text) input XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Supplement>
        <ID>321
        <SupplementType>
            <Glass>31DK</Glass>
        </SupplementType>
        </ID>
    </Supplement>
    <Supplement>
        <ID>425
        <SupplementType>
            <Glass>444d</Glass>
        </SupplementType>
        </ID>
    </Supplement>
</root>
```

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Supplement">
        <ProfileSpecification>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ID/text()[1])"/>
        </ProfileSpecification>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <ProfileSpecification>321</ProfileSpecification>
    <ProfileSpecification>425</ProfileSpecification>
</root>
```

Comment: "*you should not simply match / ... if you can directly match and address the elements that are important.*" That's a very problematic advice, IMHO. Any ancestors of "the elements that are important" will be handled by the built-in template rules - and you may very easily end up with text you don't want being copied to the output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I agree, I meant to give this advice for this specific transformation, but that's not clear. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I'll try work-in your suggestion.